# GDAL usage of GPU with Windows

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I use GDAL 2.2.1, released 2017/06/23 on Windows 10. It was install with pre-compiled packages. I usually use gdalwarp, gdal_translate or gdal_grid as commands for single use, or with Python bindings for larger programs.

I haven't found a way to use Windows GPU, even with a few options I try such as -wo "USE_OPENCL=TRUE". The graph on my GPU stays still and flat (0.0%). Here is an example of code to resample an image:

```
gdalwarp -r cubicspline -tr 4.5e-5 4.5e-5 -ot Int16 -te  3 41 8 45 -multi -wo "USE_OPENCL=TRUE" DEM_75m.tif DEM_5m.tif
```

During the processing, RAM is used at 200Mo, 20% of CPU and of course 100% of hard-drive usage. 0% GPU.

Should I re-install GDAL with new build parameters, or is there a way of using it as it is?

Comment: You must have a GDAL version that is compiled with OpenCL supporr. Perhaps this mail helps http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-GDAL-using-Nvidia-won-t-use-OpenCL-td5250622.html. But if your hard drive has already 100% load then using GPU obviously would not make the process any faster if you do not acquire faster disks by the same.  Did you notice  that you have 80% of CPU capacity unused because of slow disks?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to recompile gdal with opencl / cuda. You will need the cuda toolkit installed. 
Once thats done, your call to gdalwarp looks correct.
Even once it's working you'll likely see that there is a lot of time spent transferring the data to the GPU and back again.